# How to remove content from UITableViewCell but still have separator left?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

In my app, i have table view in which i am reloading data based on Business logic so it was overlapping earlier then i write this piece of code to remove content before drawing:

```
for(UIView *view in cell.subviews){
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            [view removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
```

And now its removing everything including cell separators. Any idea how to prevent it??

Thanks,

Comment: You don't have to check whether subviews are subclasses of `UIView`. They always are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove subviews from `[cell contentView]`

If you don't know what are you doing, you should never add views or remove views from the cell directly. Use only `contentView`, `backgroundView` and `selectedBackgroundView`.

However, there is rarely a use case when you should remove all the views from a cell. Why don't you just create a new cell (or reuse one)? Or just set the `hidden` property to `YES` for the subviews?

Comment: In my situation i have to filter the data based on selection so i am reusing the cell but it was causing overlapping with the content already there in the cell so i decided to remove everything before redrawing.